# What is the maximum length I can extend the water supply/drain hose coupling for my PORTABLE DISHWASHER?

Tags: kitchens, dishwasher

I just purchased a full-size, portable dishwasher (Maytag). The water supply/drain hose coupling is not very long and I would like to extend it to approximately 10 feet long.
- Is there a maximum length at which point the dishwasher can't pump the water out?
- Is it best to cut the lines in the middle and add an extender with clamps?
- Any other advice?
Thanks...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What does the dishwasher's manual say?

Comment: I got the manual from Maytag but it is a poorly written manual with little info on the hose coupling..

Comment: Unfortunately nobody here will be able to give you an exact number for how far it can go as we aren't the manufacturers for the unit you have so you will more than likely have to try it for yourself to see if the water comes out. In general though if you aren't doing many ups and downs, where most of it is horizontal, the increase in pressure needed to overcome the friction is pretty minimal unless you are running the line a mile